# wiremock newScenarioState based on request model

Tags: scope, wiremock

I would like to use request model attributes in wiremock mappings newScenarioState field.

Is it possible to use request model attributes in `newScenarioState` field?

Example:

```
{
    "scenario" : "my-scenario",
    "newScenarioState" : "{{request.pathSegment.[1]}}",     //or {{request.someId}} ?

    "request" : {
       "urlPatternTemplate" : "/path/{someId}"
    }
}
```

Unfortunately `{{request.pathSegment.[1]}}` will be empty for newScenarioState, but it has proper value under `request` json node, looks like variable scope issue.